# intern-runner just hangs ('/client/end' publish/subscribe doesn't work?)

Tags: intern

When launched through the intern-runner command, my tests are still hanging--intern-runner never exits to give me a report and I can tell that the proxy server is still running on port 9000. The browser I specified through my config just remains open (and no, I did not set leaveRemoteOpen to true). I added some debug to lib/reporters/webdriver.js, because I saw that's what logged the "Tests complete" message. I could see that the topic.publish('/client/end') code was invoked, but nothing ever responded to this event. Doesn't lib/ClientSuite subscribe to this topic? From that module:

```
            topic.subscribe('/client/end', function (sessionId) {
                console.log("subscribed to '/client/end' for session", sessionId);
                if (sessionId === remote.session.sessionId) {
                    clearHandles();
                    // get about:blank to always collect code coverage data from the page in case it is
                    // navigated away later by some other process; this happens during self-testing when
                    // the new Leadfoot library takes over
                    remote.setHeartbeatInterval(0).get('about:blank').then(lang.hitch(dfd, 'resolve'));
                }
            })
```

But nothing ever happens, and I don't see my console.log() output. Sorry if I am bringing up things that are red herrings, but I just wanted to do some initial investigation first.

All I want is for my test to end and my JUnit and LCOV reports generated! :( What could be going wrong?

And note: no error messages are logged to the command terminal from which I invoked intern-runner config=unittest/myInternConfig. No errors (obvious ones at least) appear in terminal where Selenium server is running.

Update 03/15/15: I added this info in my last comment, but maybe comments get lost in the shuffle on Stackoverflow. In our legacy DOH tests, we used Sinon to fake a server so as to not make real I/O requests to the backend server in unittests. I didn't see a problem with keeping this in the Intern tests, but apparently, there is. When I disabled the test modules that just do

```
var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
```

(well, that, in addition to calling server.respondWith() and server.respond())

intern-runner completed, I got my reports, and etc. Then I searched for "intern with sinon" and stumbled upon https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/47, where jason0x43 linked to his Sinon-with-Intern code at https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/sinon/sinon.js. So, I found that very helpful--it seems that in my situation, Sinon's FakeXMLHttpRequest was ALSO faking requests to Intern's proxy server, and that was what was hanging the process.

So, after pretty much using jason0x43's sinon.js code to filter out the "real request," I re-enabled the problematic test modules, re-ran, and everything worked beautifully.

Again, no errors or any sort of warnings reported in terminal or browser console--it would be great if there could be some sort of head's up about this pitfall. Even if just in a Readme file.

Comment: Start by trying to run the tests directly in your browser and look for any errors in the console. Intern 3 will have improved error capture and reporting to prevent these sorts of silent failures; it’s most likely a module is failing to load, or is throwing an error when it loads.

Comment: Thanks, C Snover. But, both in the browser client and the intern-runner environment, the tests run and pass perfectly well. There are errors logged in the error tab of the browser console--but these are errors logged by some product modules that the tests exercise (some errors are due to the actual backend server that these product files call is unavailable; we're mocking a server; since these are after all unittests).

You think these product errors might be "tripping up" Intern? I would think Intern wouldn't care about these errors since the tests pass....

Comment: Just a follow-up: I disabled the tests that drove the modules logging the errors. So, no more errors logged...but still the same behavior of intern-runner hanging.

Comment: Do you actually see the result messages printed to the browser while the tests are running? If you can provide a reproducible test case that would be the way to get this addressed.

Comment: C Snover, yes, I do see result messages in the browser. But it just stops after all suites are run--no failures or errors. I think I might try commenting out suites one by one, to see if that offers any clues. I'll see about providing a reproducible testcase, but if I can do without exposing my company's product code, I definitely won't have anything until this coming weekend.

Comment: It seems that I've isolated the problematic test modules down to the ones that call Sinon's fakeServer.create() to send mocked responses from a fake server--obviously so as to avoid having to make I/O requests to a real server.

Is Sinon just not supported with Intern, period? We were using it with the old DOH tests and it just worked for us, so I didn't see the need to break something that wasn't broken. There are no errors at all in the console. I can supply a standalone recreate if that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

(I also edited my original post to add this info.) In our legacy DOH tests, we used Sinon to fake a server so as to not make real I/O requests to the backend server in unittests. I didn't see a problem with keeping this in the Intern tests, but apparently, there is. When I disabled the test modules that just do

var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

(well, that, in addition to calling server.respondWith() and server.respond())

intern-runner completed, I got my reports, and etc. Then I searched for "intern with sinon" and stumbled upon https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/47, where jason0x43 linked to his Sinon-with-Intern code at https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/sinon/sinon.js. So, I found that very helpful--it seems that in my situation, Sinon's FakeXMLHttpRequest was ALSO faking requests to Intern's proxy server, and that was what was hanging the process.

So, after pretty much using jason0x43's sinon.js code to filter out the "real request," I re-enabled the problematic test modules, re-ran, and everything worked beautifully.

Again, no errors or any sort of warnings reported in terminal or browser console--it would be great if there could be some sort of head's up about this pitfall. Even if just in a Readme file.